# confusing define directive in c++ project

Tags: c++, preprocessor, codec

I am trying to figure out what this bit of code I encountered does but can't quite seem to understand how it works.

```
#define CODEC_BIND(classname, type) codec_creator cc_##classname##_##type ((type), new classname());
```

The codec_creator is a class that assigns a specific codec to an unordered map in the constructor as seen below.

```
extern std::unordered_map <unsigned short, std::shared_ptr<codec>> g_creator_map;
class codec_creator
{
public:
    codec_creator(unsigned short pt, codec* c)
    {
        g_creator_map[pt] = std::shared_ptr<codec>(c);
    }
};
```

As I see it, CODEC_BIND is used to add different types of codecs to the unordered map by calling the constructor in codec_creator for different codec classes. I am unsure though if this is the only thing it does though. Does it have any other purpose ?

Comment: The title doesn't match your final question, what's the real one? The code is incomplete, so even trying to answer your question it's almost impossible. how can we make proposals? It sounds like you understand what the define directive does, so what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro expands into a variable declaration (when used properly), probably used to create global variables.

The variable type is `codec_creator`, the name is based off of the specific `classname` (an unsigned short number) and `type` values passed to the macro using the [`##` preprocessor operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). The variable's constructor call will pass the `classname` value and a newly constructed object of the `type`. This constructor will then store this class object pointer in the `g_creator_map` map. The variable constructed by the macro will have minimal size, because the class has no member variables.